# From perl, why does a backticked call to a c-shell pass quoted string ok if called with tcsh but not source?

Tags: perl, csh, tcsh

I need to write a perl script that calls a c-shell script that calls yet another perl script.  I cannot change the c-shell script or the perl script it calls.  One of the args that needs to be passed is a quotes string with spaces.  If I use backticks to call the c-shell, and I run the c-shell with tcsh, the quoted string is respected as a single entity.  However, if I run the c-shell with source, it is not.

I feel that I need to use 'source' because when the c-shell is called by users from the command line, it is called through an alias that sources the c-shell.  E.g.

```
alias top "source top.csh"
```

Consider these...

topmost.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

print "Try with tcsh...\n";
my $msg = `tcsh ./top.csh -arg1 "this line has spaces"`;
print "$msg\n";

print "Try with source...\n";
my $msg = `source ./top.csh -arg1 "this line has spaces"`;
print "$msg\n";

exit;
```

top.csh is simply....

```
perl ./subperl.pl $*:q
exit
```

And subperl.pl is...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

print "In subperl.pl\n";

foreach $x (@ARGV) {
    print "$x\n";
}
print "The End\n";

exit;
```

When I run the topmost.pl script, I get...

```
Try with tcsh...
In subperl.pl
-arg1
this line has spaces
The End

Try with source...
In subperl.pl
-arg1
this
line
has
spaces:q
The End
```

Why does the "sourced" call to the top.csh script fail to respect the quotes ?

Comment: Why are you sourcing a csh script in `sh`?

Answer (score 4):

[@Kaz has the answer as to why your code isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48590681/14660). This answer is about how to avoid this class of problems entirely.

First, if you can, add a `#!/bin/tcsh` to `top.csh` and make it executable (ie. `chmod +x`). Now it can be executed as `top.csh` without needing to know what shell to use.

Then you'll want to avoid using ``` `` ``` for anything but very simple commands. This is because ``` `` ``` is interpreted by the shell and now you need to worry about shell special characters and escapes and spaces... it's a mess. What you need is a way to call external programs *without* invoking a shell.

You can do this by passing a list to [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), but `system` cannot capture the output.

```
system "tcsh", "./top.csh", "-arg1", "this line has spaces";
```

While you can cobble something together with [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and pipes, it's better to use a pre-existing library such as [IPC::System::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple).

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw(capturex);

# Or capturex("./top.csh", ...) if you add a #! to top.csh.
my $msg = capturex("tcsh", "./top.csh", "-arg1", "this line has spaces");
```

For more involved interactions with executables, look into [System::Command](https://metacpan.org/pod/System::Command) or [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run).

---

Needless to say, Perl scripts which call shell scripts which call Perl scripts is a bit of a nightmare to maintain. Rather than do that, it is better to scoop the guts of `subperl.pl` out into a Perl library and have both `subperl.pl` and your code use that library.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation.  I don't have control over top.csh  or the perl it calls :-(.  I hate to do all this nested calling, but I'm stuck.  I will definately look into capturex.  I tried CaptureOutput::capture_exec_combined but couldn't 'source' from it.  Turns out, I need to 'source' it to get the env vars.

Comment: Great advice through and through. I'd also recommend `Capture::Tiny` and `IPC::Run3`

Comment: > *This answer is about how to avoid this class of problems entirely.* Oh, I have one for that: don't use the @#$% C shell for scripting.

Comment: @daveg Sorry, but you cannot get environment variables from another process. The environment can only be inherited from a parent process, never from a child. `source` works by the shell executing shell code in the same process, like `require` in Perl. But if you try ` `source ...` ` in Perl, Perl forks a new child shell process (inheriting Perl's environment) which then executes the shell code gaining any changes to its environment. Then that process shuts down and its environment goes away. Perl's environment, the parent process, is unaffected.

Comment: @daveg I suspect you're working with a system built entirely in shell. These have a tendency to have configuration information set in shell scripts as environment variables. These are only accessible to other shell scripts via `source`ing the script. A good solution is to move these out into a common config file written in something like JSON and have everything refer to that. A work-around is to write a shell script which `source`s the relevant scripts and prints out the environment variables so other programs can read them in.

Answer (score -1):

The command in backticks is being interpreted by your system interpreter (invoked via `/bin/sh`), which I'm guessing might be GNU Bash. Or, in any case, it seems to be some shell which understands the `source` command, and almost certainly a POSIX-like shell. That `source` command quite probably tells that shell to read a script **written in that shell's own language**. So, for instance, if that shell happens to be Bash, it will treat that as a Bash script<sup>1</sup>, not as a Tcsh script.

The only way both could work is if the script is a ["polyglot"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)): a program which can be interpreted by either `tcsh` or the system shell that is used by perl to implement backticks.

(An easy example of a C Shell + POSIX shell polyglot is a script that contains nothing but a sequence of trivial commands consisting of space separated words like `cp from to`.)

Your script isn't a polyglot; only Tcsh understands the `:q` syntax, not the other shell.

---

1. More precisely, if `/bin/sh` is Bash, the original `source ...` command as well as the contents of the sourced `top.csh` script will be treated as a POSIX-mode Bash script, since when Bash is invoked as `/bin/sh`, it turns off its POSIX-incompatible behaviors. So even if Bash's pathname expansion supported the Tcsh `:q` mechanism, it would almost certainly be turned off under POSIX mode because `$*:q` already has a firm meaning in POSIX.

Comment: the system interpreter is c-shell

Comment: @Daveg [Backticks will always use `/bin/sh`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).

Comment: @Schwern While `/bin/sh` may be and often is a link to another shell.  However, that is indeed unlikely to be (or never is?) `tcsh`

Comment: Re "*The command in backticks is being interpreted by your system interpreter*", No, it's executed by `/bin/sh`. (Technically, it's executed by the program returned by `perl -V:sh`.)

Comment: Re "*`/bin/sh` is bash on a lot of systems.*", I never said otherwise. I just pointed out that "The command in backticks is being interpreted by your system interpreter"" is wrong. No idea what a "system interpreter is", but the choice is not up to the system at all.

Comment: For that matter, "*`bash` will treat that as a `bash` script!*" is also wrong. When executed as `sh`, `bash` tries to emulate `sh`.

Comment: huh? "*The command in backticks is being interpreted by your command interpreter*" is makes no sense. There's no such thing as "*your* command interpreter".

Comment: Re "*explicit use of certain extensions like source will continue to work.*", Why do you keep bringing up these straw men. I never said it wouldn't work.

Comment: Re "*Your comments are not constructive.*", Sorry, I don't see any easy way to fix your answer, or I would have done it. I can only point out the many problems with it.

Comment: Re "*command is treated similarly to system("command ...")*", That's wrong too. Aside from the non-capturing aspect, there are many differences between backticks and Perl's `system`, and C's.